# Express Morgan logs different status code than what client receives

Tags: express, morgan

I just noticed that `morgan` logs a different status code in the console for express responses than what the client receives.

I enabled morgan like this:

```js
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

Then when getting `/home`, morgan logs **304**:

> GET /v1/home 304 17.580 ms - -

On the client side, I am using [wretch](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch), and it shows that the response code is **200**:

```js
const apiResponse = wretch()
    .url(`${BASE_URL}/v1`)
    .options({
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
    })
    .url('/home')
    .get();

const resHeader = await apiResponse.res();
console.log(resHeader.status); // 200
```

The backend simply uses express' `res.json` to send the response:

```js
return res.json(someJson);
```

Why does the status code not match the one morgan logs?

Comment: 304 from the server means "not modified", i.e. the copy of the resource the client already has can continue to be used. If you look in the network panel, you should see 304 received. It's exposed to your code as 200 because the overall result is: everything is fine, here's the resource.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But what if I want to write client side logic in case of 304? I.e., not to rerender anything if I get 304? This is in react native by the way, not the browser.

Comment: Let React optimise that out - you don't necessarily know whether that 304 is from the last version your component was rendered with, rather than the local cache being updated by some other request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe All right thank you. I also just found this: https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/241. Fetch/the browser is responsible for returning the 200, and wretch is based on fetch.